# open new screen on button click in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm newbie in `swift iOS`. In my storyboard, I've created some dynamic fields from `viewController`. Have created a button from object library.

Now I need to open an new empty screen after clicking this button.
In the new screen, there'll be some input fields. I'll create those through programming or object library.

But I'm unable to open the empty screen.

```
@IBAction func SaveTgw(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("test=====")

}
```

I need to include the screen opening code within `SaveTgw`. Any help or any descriptive tutorial link would be appreciated....

Comment: check below answer

Comment: yes - I'm checking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1-From Utilities open identity inspector in storyboard ID enter id "MySecondSecreen"

[image]

2-In your method add the following code :

```
@IBAction func SaveTgw(sender: AnyObject) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MySecondSecreen") as! UIViewController; // MySecondSecreen the storyboard ID
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `SecondViewController` in Main.storyboard like this -

[image]
On `Scan` button click , do following code

```
@IBAction func scanAction(sender: AnyObject) {
     let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController
self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated:true, completion:nil) 
}
```

There are many answers available, just do a search -

- [Swift: Navigate to new ViewController using button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094923/swift-navigate-to-new-viewcontroller-using-button)
- [Swift - Change view controller using action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541302/swift-change-view-controller-using-action-button)

Answer (score 1):

Do simple way.  Connect segue from firstViewController to secondViewController.Next click the segue goto show attribute inspector (top 3rd option from right side).In identifier give "your text".
write below line into your button action.
        performSegueWithIdentifier("your text", sender: nil)

Answer (score 1):

just use this , with code 
swift 2,3x,4x

**if nib exist,**
    let vc =

```
YourViewControllerName(nibName:"YourViewControllerName",bundle:nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,animated:true)
```

**if no nib**

```
let vc = YourViewControllerName()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,animated:true)
```

Comment: what do you mean by nib?

Comment: my bad it should be xib. :)

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 4**

Based on @AbedalkareemOmreyh's answer:

1. Go to Utilities, open identity inspector and enter the ID "MySecondSecreen" in the storyboard ID.
2. Add the following code to your button:

   ```
   @IBAction func SaveTgw(sender: AnyObject) {
      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
      let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MySecondSecreen")
                 self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
   }
   ```